# Retrieving the position of relative element to window

Tags: javascript

What is the most accurate way of retrieving top position of relative positioned element to window?

i know about `getBoundingClientRect()` but this returned wrong numbers.

I have several elements ( relative positioned ) inside containers and need to retrieve elements offsetTop to window top. The containers are both relative or absolute positioned. Is there any method without iterating over parent elements and so on?

Comment: Could you please show us your code? `getBoundingClientRect` can't be wrong.

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect` is the way to go, but you might have to add the scrolled distance, subtract the clientHeight etc. to get the values you want.

Comment: Do you mean position relative to the viewport, or relative to the whole document? If document you probably didn't account for scroll position.

Comment: _"i know about getBoundingClientRect() but this returned wrong numbers."_ How did you determine the result was "wrong"?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.your-selector')[0]
    .getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset - document.documentElement.clientTop
```

Comment: Does not work in all cases. There could be other elements that are scrolled off. You have to go up the tree from the given element looking for all scroll positions

Comment: There is a possibility that there may be "error" reports  for inline elements measuring distance from, say left, - as it may report the position of the first inline element in the block instead. Most certainly that of a span element. But that may also depend on browser vendor & version to.